# How to execute .exe on insert into SQL Server database table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm needing to execute a .exe file whenever a new row is inserted into a certain table in my SQL Server database. Not sure if I should use a trigger, stored proc, or something else. All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: In general, this is a really bad idea. Why do you want to do so? Performance will suffer quite a bit. You can, alternatively, mark the "affected rows" and produce a external program that runs periodically looking for these ones, and process them accordingly.

Comment: I need to automatically execute a print job on a Loftware print server to print a shipping label when a product is ready to be shipped. Why is this a bad idea?

Comment: Would a program like that that checks for products every second have less of a system impact than what I am suggesting?

Comment: Firing an external process on every row insertion/update could lead to serious performance issues. Maybe a periodic process (even every 60 seconds) could be a better solution. A trigger could record the need for a new label on a "labels" table, and then the periodic process could read that table only.

Comment: Any such process would have to check at most every second due to the timing of the shipping process I'm working with. How would that compare with firing an external process?

Answer (score 2):

To do something when a row is added you definitely need a trigger.
To execute an EXE, the only way I know of to do this is to use XP_CMDSHell. 
This is not enabled by default.

So, it can be done. although you may run into a permissions issue.

A better way might be to use the trigger to carry out an insert into a "jobs" table and then set up an agent job or similar that checks the table at intervals and runs the exe accordingly.

Comment: I vote for the 'exposed' table polled by a listener.